# Функция загрузки файла из памяти и функция записи в файл

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте! Это функция реализована на C#. В ней уже указан текст, который нужно зашифровать/расшифровать. Я не знаю языка с# и поэтому прошу помощи. Можете переделать эту функцию так, чтобы при запуске отображалось следующее:

> - Введите имя исходного файла: // вводим имя типа `d:\rfc795.txt`, он зашифровывается, а после
> - Введите имя зашифрованного файла: // вводим имя файла, в который будет записана зашифрованная информация, например. `d:\q.txt`, после этого файл расшифровывается.
> - Введите имя расшифрованного файла: // здесь записываем имя файла, в котором будет записана расшифрованная информация типа `d:\qq.txt`

Также можете написать функцию, которая будет выводить на экран время в миллисекундах, потраченное на зашифровывание и расшифровывание файла.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Crypto;

namespace AESDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Примерно так. Как точно, должно быть описано там откуда скачан проект.
            // В имеющейся же реализации aes комментариев практически нет. Так что разобраться трудно.
            string message = "My Secret Message";
            string key = "my_secret_key";
            Console.WriteLine("Исходное сообщение: '{0}'", message);

            byte[] message_bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
            byte[] key_bytes = new byte[64];
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(key, 0, key.Length, key_bytes, 0);
            byte[] enc_message_bytes = null;
            uint msgnum = 1;
            AES.AES_CCM_Encrypt(message_bytes, key_bytes, out enc_message_bytes, 1, msgnum);
            Console.WriteLine("Зашифрованное сообщение: '{0}'", Encoding.Default.GetString(enc_message_bytes));

            byte[] dec_message_bytes = null;
            AES.AES_CCM_Decrypt(enc_message_bytes, key_bytes, out dec_message_bytes, 1, out msgnum);
            Console.WriteLine("Расшифрованное сообщение: '{0}'", Encoding.Default.GetString(dec_message_bytes));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Домашнее задание?

Comment: типа того.

Answer (score 1):

Сишарп детям в школе скоро преподавать будут, а ты не разобрался.
И правилами тут запрещено постить в стиле "сделайте за меня". На будущее.

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Crypto;

namespace AESDemo 
{
    class Program 
    {
        const string KEY = "my_secret_key";

        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();

            Console.Write("Enter source (original) file name: ");
            string srcPath = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter destination (encrypted) file name: ");
            string dstPath = Console.ReadLine();

            string message = File.ReadAllText(srcPath);

            byte[] message_bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
            byte[] key_bytes = new byte[64];
            Encoding.Default.GetBytes(KEY, 0, KEY.Length, key_bytes, 0);
            byte[] enc_message_bytes = null;

            timer.Start();
            AES.AES_CCM_Encrypt(message_bytes, key_bytes, out enc_message_bytes, 1, 1);
            timer.Stop();

            string enc_message = Encoding.Default.GetString(enc_message_bytes);

            File.WriteAllText(dstPath, enc_message);
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption time: {0}ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.Write("Enter source (encrypted) file name: ");
            srcPath = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter destination (decrypted) file name: ");
            dstPath = Console.ReadLine();

            byte[] dec_message_bytes = null;

            timer.Restart();
            AES.AES_CCM_Decrypt(enc_message_bytes, key_bytes, out dec_message_bytes, 1, out msgnum);
            timer.Stop();

            string dec_message = Encoding.Default.GetString(dec_message_bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Decryption time: {0}ms", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            File.WriteAllText(dstPath, dec_message);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы бы и вправду написали лишь ключевые моменты, а то ТС ничему не научится.